# KnockoutJS - observables in nested templates

Tags: templates, knockout.js, nested, observable

I have implemented a simple spa with knockout js, where you can navigate between several pages, each page presenting a view model. The menu is a 2 level menu, therefore I have main pages and sub pages.
I realized this task with the template engine of knockout. Unfortunately a big problem occurred with observables in the sub pages. It just does not work. The corresponding fiddle for this simple app can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/rqa8P/10/

The Code:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// View
var View = function(page, templateName, data) {
   var self = this;

   self.page = page; 
   self.templateName = templateName;
   self.data = data; 

   //animations between page changes
   this.animatePageChange = function() {
      $('.wrapper').hide(); 
      $('.wrapper').fadeIn(3000);
      //init function for each main menu view model
      //alert(self.data.init());
    };

    //animations between sup page changes
    this.animateSubPageChange = function() {
      $('.content').hide(); 
      $('.content').fadeIn(3000);
      //init function for each sub menu view model
      //alert(self.data.init());
    }
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// MainPage1viewModel (Menu Page)
var MainPage1viewModel = {
  //Sub Pages
  subpage1view : new View("subpage1", "subpage1Tmpl", SubPage1ViewModel),
  subpage2view : new View("subpage2", "subpage2Tmpl", SubPage2ViewModel),
  subpage3view : new View("subpage3", "subpage3Tmpl", SubPage3ViewModel),

  //make the selected sub page observable
  selectedView : ko.observable(),

  init: function() {return("MainPage1viewModel init")}
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// SubPage1ViewModel (Subpage from Main Page View 1)
var SubPage1ViewModel = {
    init: function() {return("SubPage1ViewModel init")},
    somedata : ko.observable("Here comes some data!")
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// SubPage2ViewModel (Subpage from Main Page View 1)
var SubPage2ViewModel = {
    init: function() {return("SubPage2ViewModel init")},
    somedata : ko.observable("Here comes some data!")
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// SubPage3ViewModel (Subpage from Main Page View 1)
var SubPage3ViewModel = {
    init: function() {return("SubPage3ViewModel init")},
    somedata : ko.observable("Here comes some data!")
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// MainPage2 View (Main Menu)
var MainPage2viewModel = {
    //init function
    init: function() {return("MainPage2viewModel init")},

    somedata : ko.observable("Here comes some data!")
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ControlViewModel (cvm), 
var cvm = {
  //Main Pages
  mainPage1view : new View("mainpage1", "mainPage1Tmpl", MainPage1viewModel),
  mainPage2view : new View("mainpage2", "mainPage2Tmpl", MainPage2viewModel),

  //make the selected page observable
  selectedView : ko.observable(),
};

//bind the cvm view model to the index.html
ko.applyBindings(cvm);
```

For the main pages the init functions and obeservables for the view models work perfectly but if I navigate to the sub pages neither the init functions work nor the observable elements. What is here wrong and what can be a solution for this? I read somewhere all observables have to be declared in the applied view model object, but why the observables for the view models in the main pages work then and why for the subpages not, as both are not binded directly to the html? I hope someone can give me a hint how i can solve the issue, i am looking now for hours to find a good and satisfied solution where I do not have to re-structure the current architecture I choice for the web app navigation...

best regards

Comment: What browser are you using because I have the feeling it works for Chrome...or I mis your point....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that when you create your `MainPage1viewModel`, you are passing the sub-page view models into the `View` constructor, but the sub-models do not exist yet.  If you move the creation of `MainPage1viewModel1` after the creation of the 3 sub-models, then it will work properly.

Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/sfeBx/

Comment: oh man! Thank you very much, it was so clear actually...

cheers!